# Filipino crew member does needs any visa/documentation for CDG lay over?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, transit-visas, cdg

Seeking for your knowledge and expertise, 
I’m a crew member (seafarer) with a flight details ;

Fort Lauderdale- CDG 
CDG- HEL
HEL-HKG 
HKG-MNL

Question #1: do I need any visa for CDG since I’ll be staying for 3 hours to wait for my next flight?

Question #2: would there be a need of any visa /documentation from CDG-HEL since Finland is a Schengen country and again will be staying there only for 3 hrs for my HKG flight.

Comment: Just to clarify: this is all a single trip? You are flying a one-way from FLL to MNL  with layovers Paris, Helsinki and Hong Kong ? Or do you stay more than 24 hours  at any location? Single ticket or multiple tickets? (Not relevant to the question, but 3 hours in CDG on separate tickets would be awfully tight)

Comment: Where are you joining (or leaving) your vessel?

Comment: This is a question for your crew department or agency.

Comment: And that's a bit strange routing anyway. You can probably find a better routing for even cheaper. e.g. FLL-ATL-DOH-MNL on Qatar is the cheapest flight I can find right now and will avoid the need for more visas.

Answer (score 3):

Since the flight from Paris to Helsinki is an internal Schengen flight, it is effectively a domestic flight.  You will have to clear passport control in Paris to enter the Schengen zone before you can reach the gate to board your flight to Helsinki.  You will clear Schengen exit controls in Helsinki before you can reach the gate to board your flight to Hong Kong.  You therefore need a Schengen short-stay visa (type C).  An airport transit visa (type A) will not suffice.